# Set mouse cursor behavior globally

Tags: flutter, dart, mouse-cursor

I'm currently developing a windows app with flutter. I experienced that the default mouse cursor changes when hovering over a button that is clickable or shows an "forbidden" sign if a button is deactivated. This does not feel right for me and I think in most Windows programs there is just the standard cursor.

I know about the `MouseRegion` class where I can set the cursor for one button. Is there a way to change the cursor globally for the entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, overall, the cursor topic is still in progress for Flutter. We have been developing a Desktop application for almost two years now and I can definitely tell that, there is a progress but still it is a problem.

What we do most of the time is to create our own buttons and arrange all of them together.

However, to answer your question :) Assuming that you are using new material buttons on the latest Flutter version, in the new Material Buttons [shared here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10Fbn59hiHkppqJ6y_1Rjwl7klN-OvJXQU3SFEqicpME/edit). You can see that, `ButtonStyle` class has a field called `final MaterialStateProperty<MouseCursor> mouseCursor;` which is the `mouseCursor` that you can use for your own buttons.

Comment: That is not that satisfying but an acceptable solution. Thanks for your insights!